# Celery worker doesn't takes updated values from the database

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a webapp using flask and using celery to send mails periodically.
The problem is, whenever the there is a new entry in the database, celery doesn't sees it and continues to use the old entries. I have to restart the celery worker each time to make it work properly. Celery beat is running and I am using redis as a broker.

Celery related functions:

```
@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, appointment_checkout, name='appointment_checkout')


@celery.task(name='app.Blueprints.periods.appointment_checkout')
def appointment_checkout():
    from app.Blueprints.api.routes import fetchAllAppointments, fetch_user_email, fetch_user_phone
    from app.Blueprints import db
    dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
    #fa = Appointment.query.filter_by(date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    fa = fetchAllAppointments()
    for i in fa:
        # send emails to clients and counsellors
        try:
            if(str(i.date.year) != dt.strftime("%Y") or str(i.date.month) != dt.strftime("%m") or str(i.date.day) != dt.strftime("%d")):
                continue
        except:
            continue
        if(i.reminderFlag == 1):
            continue
        if(int(dt.strftime("%H")) == int(i.time.hour) and int(dt.strftime("%M")) == int(i.time.minute)):
            client = fetch_user_email(i.user)
            counsellor = fetch_user_email(i.counsellor)
            client_phone = fetch_user_phone(i.user)
            counsellor_phone = fetch_user_phone(i.counsellor)
            i.reminderFlag = 1 
            db.session.add(i)
            db.session.commit()
            # client email
            subject = "appointment notification"
            msg = "<h1>Greetings</h1></p>This is to notify you that your appointment is about to begin soon.</p>"
            sendmail.delay(subject, msg, client)
            sendmail.delay(subject, msg, counsellor)
            sendmsg.delay(client_phone, msg)
            sendmsg.delay(counsellor_phone, msg)
```

When I add something in the `appointment` table, celery doesn't sees the new entry. After restarting the celery worker it sees it.

I am running beat and worker using the following commands:

```
celery -A periods beat --loglevel=INFO

celery -A periods worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=2
```

Comment: _doesn't sees the new entry_ db commits may take a while. Your task runs every 30 seconds, have you tried making celery work for an extended period of time (like 10 mins)?

Comment: You didn't post anything about which rdbms you're using and how the connection is configured, but chances are you have a transaction isolation level issue, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: @Fian By new entry I don't mean setting the `reminderFlag = 1`. I mean if a new appointment is added in the appointment table, it won;t show in `fa`